# Logic Apps - for each loop with liquid from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, liquid, azure-logic-apps

Im learning logic apps and im trying to create a simple flow from azure blob storage, perform a liguid parsing and then save parsed file to another blob container.

How should it work:
1. Whenever new file is added to blob container ("from") [containing xml files]
2.Liquid action takes place (XML -> JSON) 
3.New file .json is saved to blob container ("too") :)

What i have learned:
1. I manage to write a liguid template for xml files - tested - working 
2. I know how to copy file between blob containers  - tested - working

For  each loop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlWLT.jpg "FE loop"

Completed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8YF.jpg "Completed..."

Current LA:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlWLT.jpg "Current"

What I dont know how to do:
1. How to "insert" current file content in for each into liquid action? It looks like logic apps is skipping that step?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you could not use `Current item` as the xml content, you need to get the content with `Get blob content` action in For_each,  then parse xml to json. After this create the blob in another container with json value.

You could refer to my workflow.

[image]

Comment: How did you manage to put "value" as output from previous step in for each ? What is you trigger? When I use "When a blob storage is added or modified" output for each is only "list  of files"....